# Bibtex and abbreviation of author names with non-latin first letter

Tags: bibtex, unicode, author

The following code produces wrong bibliography:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn, sort&compress]{elsarticle} 
\journal{FGCS}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\begin{document}

\cite{cai-two-layer}
\section*{References}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliographystyle{alpha}
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

The bibtex entry is:

```
@article{cai-two-layer,
    author = {Łukasz Opio\l{}a and Micha\l{} Wrzeszcz and \L{}ukasz Dutka 
    and Renata S\l{}ota and Jacek Kitowski},
    title = {{Two-Layer Load Balancing for Onedata System}},
    journal ={Computing and Informatics},
    volume = {37},
    number = {1},
    year = {2018},
    pages = {1-22},
    note = {in press},
}
```

And the result is:

[image: bibtex problem]

As you can see if the macro \L{} is used then the letter (see the third auhor) is not barred and if UTF-8 char Ł is used then the name is not abbreviated (see the first author). The abbreviation should be Ł. Any help?

Comment: `bibtex` isn't good at unicode. As for the second case, you could use `{\L}ukasz` to get barred abbreviation. Though I'd advise to switch to `biblatex` and `biber` if it's acceptable.

Comment: On the other hand, `elsarticle` isn't compatible with `biblatex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{\L{}}ukasz` for proper abbreviating in this case.

In more detail, the code:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn, sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\journal{FGCS}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}% make the MWE self-contained
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
  @article{cai-two-layer,
  author = {Łukasz Opio\l{}a and Micha\l{} Wrzeszcz and {\L{}}ukasz Dutka
    and Renata S\l{}ota and Jacek Kitowski},
    title = {{Two-Layer Load Balancing for Onedata System}},
    journal ={Computing and Informatics},
    volume = {37},
    number = {1},
    year = {2018},
    pages = {1-22},
    note = {in press},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\cite{cai-two-layer}
\section*{References}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliographystyle{alpha}
%\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Comment: This answer is correct so I am not sure why there is a down-vote. This said, it would be better if you gave more details and packaged this as a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), showing that what you are suggesting works. I have just done this for you.

Comment: I think it would be better if you set the `author` field as `author = {{\L}ukasz Opio{\l}a and Micha{\l} Wrzeszcz and {\L}ukasz Dutka and Renata S{\l}ota and Jacek Kitowski},`. That way, all first names will be abbreviated, incl. the first name of the lead author.